# Mach a string with the same string from another data frame

Tags: r, matching, string-matching

I have this dataframe (DF1)

```
structure(list(ID = 1:3, Text = c("there was not clostridium", "clostridium difficile positive", "test was OK")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) 

ID TEXT
1  "there was not clostridium"
2  "clostridium difficile positive"
3  "test was OK"
```

and dataframe (DF2)

```
structure(list(ID = 1:3, Microorganisms = c("ESCHERICHIA COLI", "CLOSTRIDIUM DIFFICILE", "FUNGI")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

ID Microorganisms
1  ESCHERICHIA COLI
2  CLOSTRIDIUM DIFFICILE
3  FUNGI
```

And I would like with regex find matches DF1 and DF2 and put them to a new column like this

```
ID TEXT                                Microorganism
1  "there was not clostridium"         CLOSTRIDIUM DIFFICILE
2  "clostridium difficile positive"    CLOSTRIDIUM DIFFICILE
3  "test was OK"                       no
```

I have tried something like this

```
DF1 %>% mutate(Mikroorganism = ifelse(grepl(DF2$Microorganisms, TEXT), str_extract(TEXT, DF2$Microorganisms), "no"))
```

But it was not the way.

Comment: A simple regex is not going to work with your first row: there is no `"difficile"`. Are you looking for a match of any of the words in `DF2`, not the string as a whole?

Comment: Yes, I would like to match of any of the words in DF2. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is using the `fuzzyjoin` package.

```r
DF1 %>%
  fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(
    transmute(DF2, Microorganisms, ptn = gsub("\\s+", "|", Microorganisms)),
    by = c("Text" = "ptn"), ignore_case = TRUE) %>%
  select(-ptn)
#   ID                           Text        Microorganisms
# 1  1      there was not clostridium CLOSTRIDIUM DIFFICILE
# 2  2 clostridium difficile positive CLOSTRIDIUM DIFFICILE
# 3  3                    test was OK                  <NA>
```

Comment: Will it work when in Text column in DF 1 is more than one string? I mean instead of just "there was not clostridium" will be c("there was not clostridium", "some text", "some text)